# Helm3 Upgrade Requires Two Arguments, But I Provided The Arguements

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am currently attempting to install/deploy an application to K8s via helm 3 and gitlab. Coming across the error:

> Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

I am passing the necessary parameters like so:

> helm3 upgrade myproject ./helm/myproject --install --force --namespace=${NAMESPACE} --set rbac.create=true gitlab/gitlab-runner

However, I am still obtaining the same error. There are no unnecessary spaces that i can see. The space between "***rbac.create=true gitlab/gitlab-runner***" is valid.

Comment: I see _three_ parameters that aren't obviously attached to an option – `myproject`, `./helm/myproject`, `gitlab/gitlab-runner`.  `myproject` is probably the release name; which one is the chart name or location?

Comment: @DavidMaze location to the chart is "./helm/myproject"

Comment: What is `gitlab/gitlab-runner` as an argument, then?

Comment: old but one thing I see wrong is that your `--set rbac.create=true gitlab/gitlabrunner` is wrong. You either need to remove `./helm/myproject` in favor of `gitlab/gitlab-runner` or the other way around, and typically the chart is right after the release argument meaning that `./helm/myproject` is the release argument, but so is `gitlab/gitlab-runner`.